# Receiving "WebpackError: Element type is invalid..." error from peer dependencies I don't have control over when building Gatsby

Tags: npm, webpack, dependencies, gatsby

Full error message

`WebpackError: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

each time I run `gatsby build`

It's always coming from a package that I am not directly importing into my application but I guess from peer dependencies.

For example:

```
29 |         }
30 |         return this;

> 31 |     };
> | ^
> 32 |     Crc32.prototype.digest = function () {
> 33 |         return (this.checksum ^ 0xffffffff) \>\>\> 0;
> 34 |     };

WebpackError: Element type is invalid: expected a string (f
or built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
components) but got: undefined.

- index.js:31
  \[\~my app\~\]/\[@aws-crypto\]/crc32/build/index.js:31:1\
```

or

```
  31 |     result = typeof number === 'string' ? '' : [];
  32 |
> 33 |     if (!this.isValid(number)) {
     | ^
  34 |         throw new Error('Number "' + number + '" contains of 
non-alphabetic digits (' + this.srcAlphabet + ')');
  35 |     }
  36 |


  WebpackError: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in compo
  nents) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
  
  - converter.js:33 
    [~my app~]/[any-base]/src/converter.js:33:1
```

Not directly importing either of those packages but they are like 3rd degree peer dependencies, which is frustrating. Dependencies of a dependency of my actual dependency

For example: any-base -> short-uuid -> gatsby-background-image (that's my actual dependency and what I'm importing into my code)

Any straight forward solution for this or am I going to have to find alternate dependencies for each one where the peer dependency is breaking?

I've tried everything. Everything I've seen so far on SO has been for issues with directly imported packages causing the error. My case seems different because they are coming from code in my node_modules